# Is anyone know the alternative of https://botbuilder.myget.org/ site as currently is not working

Tags: botframework, myget

unable to download packages from botbuilder.myget.org and due to that enable to build the microsoft composer porject with yarn install.

trying to download packages from  botbuilder.myget.org and running yarn install but its getting timeout from botbuilder.myget.org

Do you any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

MyGet has been retired in favor of an [Azure DevOps Feed](https://dev.azure.com/ConversationalAI/BotFramework/_artifacts/feed/SDK). You can connect to this feed instead to download preview packages.

That said, I would recommend you do not configure your build process to depend on a preview feed. There is no guarantee that nightly packages will continue to be available in the same feed indefinitely, nor any guarantee that they will function correctly.